# How to implement oAuth 2.0 client credentials flow in NetSuite. As i am getting 400 Bad Request below is the code that i tried in dotnet

Tags: oauth-2.0

Hi All can anyone help me out on this.

I have done below steps

Created a self signed cert:

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -keyout auth-key.pem -out auth-cert.pem -nodes -days 730

Added the auth-cert.pem to the integration in NetSuite and able to create integration record

Tried calling the TokenUrl endpoint to get access token

I keep getting Bad Request (Status code 400) when I call
GetNSAccessToken(string signedJWTAssertion) to get access token from TokenUrl.

below is the code tried in c#.net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jwt = GenerateNSJWTPEMFile("auth-key.pem");
            var accessToken = GetNSAccessToken(signedJWTAssertion: jwt);
        }

        public static string GenerateNSJWTPEMFile(string PEMFile)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var rsaPem = File.ReadAllText(PEMFile);
            var privatekey = RSA.Create();
            privatekey.ImportFromPem(rsaPem);
            var key = new RsaSecurityKey(privatekey);
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                key: key,
                algorithm: SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256
            );
            var Now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            var Exp = Now.AddMinutes(30).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            var Iat = Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            var Scope = "restlets";
            var Aud = "https://xxxxxxx-sb2.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/auth/oauth2/v1/token";
            var Issuer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var jwt = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = Issuer,
                Claims = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    ["iss"] = Issuer,
                    ["scope"] = Scope,
                    ["aud"] = Aud,
                    ["exp"] = Exp,
                    ["iat"] = Iat
                },
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
            };
            var jws = tokenHandler.CreateToken(jwt);
            var encoded = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jws);
            return encoded;
        }

        public static string GetNSAccessToken(string signedJWTAssertion)
        {
            string accessToken;
            string TokenUrl = "https://xxxxxxx-sb2.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/auth/oauth2/v1/token";
            HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_assertion", signedJWTAssertion)
            };
            using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams))
            {
                var response = _httpClient.PostAsync(TokenUrl, content).Result;
                var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                accessToken = responseContent;
            }
            return accessToken;
        }
```